# Getting circular import error when trying to get data from another Python file and running it inside the main Flask file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Basically I have two files

1. app.py
2. test.py

app.py is the main flask application, I tried to push URL inputs from app.py to test.py and then it will do a job and then return the result back to the app.py function so that it can display the result. But when I'm trying to do that it is giving me circular import error!

```
app.py

from test import func

@app.route('/view/<string:domain>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test(domain):
    return domain
def view():
    return func
```

And this is the test.py file:

```
test.py


from app import test
def func:
 print(test())
```

I tried only taking the data from app.py and run it in test.py which works perfectly like this:

```
app.py

@app.route('/view/<string:domain>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test(domain):
    return domain
```

Here it is printing the domain

```
test.py


from app import test

print(test())
```

But this approach only works if i run test.py so I thought I can maybe use os command to run the test.py file and get the data but I don't think that's a standard approach also it won't make the process efficient. I tried creating a class but I'm not so familiar with the classes yet so I would prefer other solutions.

Basically, I'm trying to perform something like this, but I am open to better suggestions:

```
app.py >>> sends data for test func (domain) >>> test.py gets the value and runs the operation >>> test.py sends the output back to app.py after the operation
```

Comment: A simple way to avoid the circular dependency in your test code is to move the "from test import func" line to inside the view function where you use it.  It may not be the right way, and there might be some architectural changes you could make, but that is a way to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @saquintes as he recommended to put the importing inside the function. So this was occurring because app.py tried to import the values in the first line itself so when it tries to get the value it doesn't find anything because nothing is happening in test.py but if you put it inside the function then value gets assigned and it manages to import the value.

```
app.py



@app.route('/view/<string:domain>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test(domain):
    return domain
def view():
    from test import func
    return func
```

And this is the test.py file:

```
test.py


from app import test
def func:
 print(test())
```